# Trying to accept a socket connection, retrieve and process a message, and then write this message to the terminal

Tags: c, file, sockets, stream, file-descriptor

I need to write a program to retrieve and process a message through a socket. I have no trouble and understand the process of creating the socket, binding the socket, listening for the incoming connection and then accepting it. I have trouble with receiving the message from the file stream that I have created for the accepted connection. My code is below (I've included pretty much all of it for reference but I think the problem comes after the connection is accepted..):

```
int sockfd; // the socket file descriptor
int conn_fd; // the accepted connection file descriptor
FILE *conn_fs; // the file stream for the accepted connection
char *conn_buff;
//char conn_buff[LINE_MAX]; // a buffer to store the data received from the accepted connection

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int port = 0;
if ((argc != 2) || (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &port) != 1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [PORT]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

if (port < 1024) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Port must be greater than 1024\n");
    exit(1);
}

struct sockaddr_in servaddr; // socket address structure (socket in address)
// set all bytes in socket address structure to zero, and fill in the relevant data members
memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(port); // port is the first argument given in the terminal

// tell the user the servaddr structure has been initialised.
//printf("servaddr structure has been initialised..\n\ncreating socket..\n");

// create the socket using IPv4 (AF_INET) and 2-way comms (SOCK_STREAM)
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) { // socket() returns < 0 if an error occurs
    printf("error: creating the socket..\nexitting..\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// tell the user the socket has been created
//printf("socket created..\n\nbinding socket..\n"); 

// bind the socket to the socket address structure defined above
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) { // bind() returns < 0 if an error occurs
    printf("error: binding the socket..\nexitting..\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// tell the user the socket is "bound"
//printf("socket is now \"bound\"..\n\nmarking the socket as passive..\n");

// set the socket to accept incoming connections (listen)
if (listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) < 0) { // listen() returns < 0 if an error occurs
    printf("error: marking the socket as a passive socket in the function listen()..\nexitting..\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// tell the user the socket is listening for incoming connections
printf("socket is now passive (listening)..\n\naccepting incoming connections..\n");

// accept an incoming connection
if (conn_fd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL) < 0) { // accept() returns < 0 if an error occurs
    printf("error: accepting an incoming connection..\nexitting..\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// tell the user a connection has been accepted
printf("a connection has been accepted..\n\ncreating a file stream for this connection..\n");
    /*
// open a file stream associated with conn_fd
if ((conn_fs = fdopen(conn_fd, "r+")) == NULL) { // fdopen() returns NULL if an error occurs
    printf("error: associating a stream to the connections file descriptor in the function fdopen()..\nexitting..\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

    // echo out the incoming message
    /*while (fgets(conn_buff, LINE_MAX, conn_fd) != NULL) { // fill the conn_buff buffer with data from the file stream conn_fs. returns NULL on error or EOF
    //while (read(conn_fd,conn_buff,sizeof(char)*LINE_MAX) > 0) {
        printf(conn_buff);printf("OH HAIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\n");
    } printf("OH HAI\n");*/        

    size_t len = 100;
    ssize_t read;
    while ((read = getline(&conn_buff, &len, conn_fs)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", conn_buff);
    }

    free(conn_buff);

    // check if there was an error
    if (ferror(conn_fs) != 0) { // returns nonzero if the error indicator is set for conn_fs (eg, if fgets() above returned NULL due to an error)
        printf("error: an error occurred whilst retrieving data from the stream..\nexitting..\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// close the file stream associated with conn_fd
if (close((int) conn_fs) != 0) { // close the file stream
    printf("error: closing the file stream..\nexitting..\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I run the program, it stops inside the `while ((read = getline(...` loop. If I hit enter to flush the buffer then I get "Retrieved line of length 1 : " from the terminal. I figured out that the program is (for some reason I cannot understand) reading from stdin. It waits for me to type anything and as soon as I flush the buffer (ie hit enter) it sends it all back to me. The only way to close the program is using Ctrl+C. For this reason I think there is a problem with my `if ((conn_fs = fdopen(conn_fd, "r+")) == NULL) {` statement.

I have tried MANY different ways of reading from the stream (fread(), read(), getline(), fgets(), fgetc()...) and they all had the same effect. Then when I realised the problem must be with how I open the file stream, I tried using fopen() but to no avail.

I'm probably making a stupid mistake but can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: the portion where you do if(conn_fs = fdopen(conn_fd,"r+)).. seems to be commented out. Is this your original code?

Comment: by the way, close((int) conn_fs) is wrong. close accepts file descriptor argument not FILE*.

Answer (score 0):

The client is never closing the connection.